# Why can I access asp:TextBox in javascript, but not asp:Label?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is a simple demonstration of what I'm talking about

js in head tag:

```
  function changeTxt(frm){
    var lblo = frm.txt1;
    lblo.value = "hey guy";

    var lbl = frm.lblStatus;
    lbl.innerHTML = "hello world";
  }
```

aspx/html markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<button onclick="changeTxt(this.form);">go</button>
```

The js finds `txt1` (`input` html element) and changes the value. But why can it not find `lblStatus` (`span` html element)? It comes up as `undefined`. They are all in the same form.

**Edit:** The problem seems to be accessing `span` nodes in js. I guess you cannot access them through the form object like I was.

Comment: What HTML does asp:Label render?  IIRC it just outputs a `<p>` tag, or maybe even just a `<span>`

Comment: It outputs a `<span>` unless you set the `AssociatedControlID` attribute, in which case, it outputs a `<label>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asp:Label` renders as a span or label, thus `value` is not the correct way to change the text. You would need to use something like `innerHTML` Like this:

```
function changeTxt(frm){
    var lblo = document.getElementById('<%: txt1.ClientID %>');
    lblo.value = "hey guy";

    var lbl = document.getElementById('<%: lblStatus.ClientID %>');
    lbl.innerHTML = "hello world";
}
```

You should also be using `getElementById` to get the object.

Watch out for potential [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) issues when using `innerHTML`.

Comment: frm seems to be the reference to the form element. If so, this would not work. Also the ClientID should be used to access the element in the JS as the rendered ID may change depending upon where the control is.

Comment: `var lbl = frm.lblStatus;` is coming up as undefined though? It is still not working. Can you not access `<span` elements in js?

Comment: @Shredder As amit_g correctly noted you should be using `document.getElementById` to get the DOM object.

Comment: @amit_g You are correct! Why can't span elements be accessed through the form object like `input` elements can? Just curious

Comment: Because they have different API. Any element can be accessed using getElementById if the element has an ID. In addition form element can also be accessed using form.ElementName or form[elementName]. Your method was working because by default ASP.NET renders ID and NAME as same (again as long as element is not within a usercontrol or masterpage).

Answer (score 2):

The `ASP:Label` doesn't render the form element. It renders a `span` or `label`. You have to access the value using innerHTML. Make sure to use the ClientID as the ASP.NET runtime may render a different ID if the label control is not directly in the page or if master page is used.

```
var lbl = document.getElementById("<%= lblStatus.ClientID %>");
lbl.innerHTML = "hello world";
```